# Ruby: Why does equals sign in literal regexp cause parsing error?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

These parse and execute fine:

```
"=".scan(/=/)
"=".scan (/=/)
```

This causes "unterminated regexp meets end of file":

```
"=".scan /=/
```

If I insert something before the `=` the error goes away:

```
"=".scan /^=/
```

What's going on?

Comment: I think it's parsing it as ("=".scan )/(=/)

Comment: Noting that `"=".scan /\=/` also works.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: I'd guess `('='.scan) /= (/)` and that the op= special case in the parser is guessing wrong. Maybe not though.

Comment: @muistooshort your one makes more sense given some of the things that do work

Comment: @muistooshort I also guessed that the first slash is being interpreted as part of an "operator-equals". So far, that's the theory that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're hitting [this in the parser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L7436):

```
case '/':
    if (IS_BEG()) {
        lex_strterm = NEW_STRTERM(str_regexp, '/', 0);
        return tREGEXP_BEG;
    }
    if ((c = nextc()) == '=') {
        set_yylval_id('/');
        lex_state = EXPR_BEG;
        return tOP_ASGN;
    }
```

Note the `nextc()` check in the second `if`. For reference, [`tOP_ASGN` is](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L726):

```
%token <id> tOP_ASGN    /* +=, -=  etc. */
```

so it is used for operator-assign tokens.

This suggests that that `/=/` in

```
'='.scan /=/
```

is being seen as the divide-assign operator (`/=`) followed by a start-regex-literal (`/`).

You'll have trouble (of a slightly different sort) with this:

```
' ='.scan / =/
```

but not this:

```
' ='.scan(/ =/)
```

There is often ambiguity when a method call doesn't have parentheses. In this case, I think operator precedence rules apply and that's not what you're expecting.

I tend to put parentheses on all my method calls because I'm too old and cranky to want to worry about how the parser is going to behave.

Comment: But obviously not too old and cranky to sift through C code :) . Ugh, `' ='.scan / =/` was another mind-bender. I assume it's parsing as though dividing by `=/`.

Comment: Or old and cranky enough to want justification for my guesses and old and cranky enough to have C burned into my brain :) I think you're right on how `/ =/` gets parsed.

Comment: +1 "I tend to put parentheses on all my method calls because I'm too old and cranky to want to worry about how the parser is going to behave." I harp on this repeatedly in code reviews. Just because we can ignore parenthesis *some times* doesn't mean we should do it.

Comment: @theTinMan: Cranky old men of the world unite! We'll get these kids off our lawns soon enough :)

Comment: Wonderful. I'm getting it even without the '='..  Is this another joke of those kids?    "".scan / /      #  unterminated regexp meets end of file .. What does it think I'm saying there?

Comment: @inger: I'd guess `"".scan() / /` where the first slash is division and the second is open-regex-literal. Maybe `''.scan(/ /)` would do The Right Thing.

Comment: @muistooshort Makes sense, thanks. Yes, parens solve everything - should go for lisp next time, cranky enough to take that now :)